# Unable to create a Modern Batch (Batch Project) in RAD 9.5 IDE

Tags: ibm-rad

Problem Statement:
Unable to create a Batch Project in RAD 9.5 IDE.

Details:
I am unable to find the Batch Project under the "Select wizard" option for RAD 9.5 although I was able to create them previous when I was using RAD 8.0.4.2.

What happens when I try to find Modern Batch(Batch Project) in RAD 9.5?
[image]

vs What happens when I try to find Modern Batch(Batch Project) in RAD 8.0?
[image]

Can someone tell me i am missing any plugin/feature which I have to addition import in RAD 9.5 although this wizard option came by default with RAD 8.0 which I used earlier.

I tried finding in various forums of IBM but nothing helped.

Anyone having any idea who have faced the similar issue earlier will be of great help..
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature isn't installed.  Start up your IBM Installation Manager and Select Modify.  Chose RAD 9.5.  Keep clicking and you should be able to find the"Java EE Batch" and "WebSphere Batch" features.

[Installation Manager Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0fE.jpg)